# What does MediaPlayer info/warning (973, 0) mean?

Tags: android, performance, media-player

I'm using MediaPlayer to play a lot of short music in my app, but I got this warning in my logcat:

> MediaPlayer info/warning (973, 0).

What does this warning mean? I searched around (in the documentation and on Google) but nothing comes up.

Also, I released the MediaPlayer 'properly'.

EDIT:

> 01-18 18:43:22.662: W/MediaPlayer(24940): info/warning (973, 0)

Comment: If you just want to play short "music(s)" I would recommend to use SoundPool instead of MediaPlayer!

Comment: Could you post the complete output line from logcat with that message? I am also wondering if the device/emulator/version you are getting it from matters.

Comment: @Joe i added the line

Comment: Are you actually having an issue? MediaPlayer will commonly spit out random messages. They can usually be ignored.

Comment: No i am not having an issue with MediaPlayer just weird warnings (not specified in the doc).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good question, the codes are somewhat buried. You will not find out what 973 is specifically, but it falls under the 9xx branch of error codes outlined in the [media.h source here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java).

What's really interesting is the 9xx errors are the only ones not referenced in the documentation, but they are labelled `MEDIA_INFO_TIMED_TEXT_ERROR`.

The description is that the player:

> Failed to handle timed text track properly.

Now what that means is also a good question to which I don't have the answer :)

But I guess either it expects or cannot parse some kind of timed text track with the music file itself. Is it an mp4 or 3gp by any chance? There is some more info in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422673/looking-for-a-working-example-of-addtimedtextsource-for-adding-subtitle-to-a-vid). But I believe it's related to a subtitle track in the media, which wouldn't make any sense for a purely audio track, but maybe there is an .srt file or similar in the vicinity of the track it's trying to parse.

Comment: thanks, i use an .ogg file. Maybe 9xx errors are overlays added by some specific constructor or MediaPlayer source wasn't updated since.

Comment: Yes I would absolutely blame the rendering of the file myself, as it's an .ogg, text can be embedded in the file through various codecs - http://wiki.xiph.org/OggText#Categories_of_Text_Codecs.

Comment: I tried with an audio/mp4 file and still got the same thing.

Comment: By audio/mp4 do you mean an mp3 and then an mp4? I don't know enough about these things but I would be interested to see if you got the same error with the mp4 sample located here: http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5

Comment: By audio/mp4 i mean an audio file with mpeg4 format

Comment: That's what I thought which makes more sense, so did you try it with the sample mp4 to see if you still get the error?

Comment: No warning with the mp4 video from the link above.

Comment: Awesome :) That means for certain it is an error with the file(s) you are trying to play, rather than the device or your code. Depending on your circumstances now you could examine how the files are / were created, or google means of stripping unnecessary info from the file - I'm sure cmd programs like ffmpeg would be helpful in this regard

Comment: Thanks ! it's a lot more clear. No luck my bounty expired yesterday :-)

Answer (score 0):

973, 0 means

```
int what, int extra
```

`what` - the type of info or warning.

`extra` - an extra code, specific to the info. Typically implementation dependent.

For more details, please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener.html).

Comment: @bijiang i didn't find what 973 means. Thanks by the way.

Comment: the link you are refering to does not contain the error code