# Why my videoview is not playing?

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm currently facing a problem that I can solve myself.

My android application (built for 4.2 and 4.4) act as a VideoPlayer. I've put some videos into the file directory of my app with no restriction access (MODE_WORLD_READABLE) and the player read them one by one until I shutdown the device or the application.

Sometimes, when I'm trying to read a local video using a [VideoView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQx83r7tjLAhXKPRoKHWimC9UQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fwidget%2FVideoView.html&usg=AFQjCNEQsizkqQrTzBYaXUVV9QiBlCoarg&sig2=RKP7FOPogP1g9hyo69MNBw&bvm=bv.117604692,d.d24)
the video doesn't start and the log print this warning :

```
03-24 12:10:50.493: W/MediaPlayer(12894): info/warning (701, 0)
```

Sometimes, the mediaplayer doesn't leave this state until I kill my app (or reboot the device).

And sometimes, the log continue after the previous warning with:

```
03-24 14:07:07.775: E/FFMpegMediaPlayer(100): start in mCurrentState in
03-24 14:07:07.775: I/FFMpegMediaPlayer(100): ******************************************
03-24 14:07:07.775: E/FFMpegMediaPlayer(100): start in mCurrentState = 8
03-24 14:07:07.775: I/FFMpegMediaPlayer(100): starting main player thread:2013-11-20 
03-24 14:07:07.775: I/RkAudioPlayer(100): mAudioSink->open in mSampleRate  = 48000 channels = 2
03-24 14:07:07.775: I/FFMpegMediaPlayer(100): ******************************************
03-24 14:07:07.775: I/FFMpegMediaPlayer(100): mCurrentState = 8
03-24 14:07:07.775: I/(100): starting thread
03-24 14:07:07.775: D/AUDIO_DECOE(100): prepare()
03-24 14:07:07.785: I/AudioHardwareALSA(100): Audio exiting sandby will open audio device
03-24 14:07:07.895: E/ALSAModule(100): audio type flag: 0

03-24 14:07:13.465: D/FFMpegMediaPlayer(100): url_feof=1,err=0 
03-24 14:07:13.465: I/FFMpegMediaPlayer(100): av_read_frame end of stream ret = -541478725
03-24 14:07:13.465: W/MediaPlayer(9652): info/warning (950, 0)
03-24 14:07:13.475: I/MediaPlayer(9652): Info (950,0)
03-24 14:07:13.475: E/ERROR : INFO MEDIAPLAYER(9652): what:950, extra:0
03-24 14:07:17.695: D/AudioHardwareALSA(100): AudioStreamOutALSA::standby().....
```

As the first log, after this one, nothing appened until I kill my app (or reboot the device).

Also, I've put some logging information in order to know if the onPrepared Callback is fired and it this is OK.

The only way I found to play the video again is to reboot my device when the problem occurred.

Here is some code of my player:

```
    audioManager = (AudioManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); //this is in the constructor of my singleton player

    //all the following code are encapsulated in a method which is called every time a new video must be play.
    setCompletionListener(); //in here I call videoview.stopPlayback(); and I recall this method to start another video
    setErrorListener(); //here too I call videoview.stopPlayback();

    videoview.setVideoPath(applicationContext.getFilesDir() + "/" + myVideoFile.getFileName());

    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new  MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 90, 0);
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(12.0f, 12.0f);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0)           
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

**My question is: Why my videoview is not playing correctly all the time ? The problem appears sometimes after 2 or 3h of execution or sometimes at the boot of my app.**

Comment: is this happenieng on other phones?

Comment: Until now, we have used only one type of device because is for a dedicated solution but we are currently trying in with a tablet. I'll give you feedbacks in some hours. Thank for your interests.

Comment: I'm guessing there could be problem with VideoView implementation itself http://www.piterwilson.com/blog/2014/03/11/android-mediaplayer-not-quite-there-yet/ If I were you i would do some more research changing sdk    build version to newest. Maybe google fixed this already.

Answer (score 1):

Code `701` means the mediaplayer is buffering more data and pausing playback temporarily, this is normal

> **public static final int [MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_STAR)**
>
> MediaPlayer is temporarily pausing playback internally in order to
>   buffer more data.
>
> `Constant Value: 701 (0x000002bd)`

Main problem is the error code `950`

```
info/warning (950, 0)
I/MediaPlayer(9652): Info (950,0)
E/ERROR : INFO MEDIAPLAYER(9652): what:950, extra:0
```

Error code `950` falls under the `9xx` branch of error codes as described here:
[What does MediaPlayer info/warning (973, 0) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912581/what-does-mediaplayer-info-warning-973-0-mean)

The error could be with the file you are trying to play, rather than the device or your code. There is some more info in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586035/any-clues-about-mediaplayer-info-warning-950).

Also try to report it as a bug as [this one](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78692&q=mediaplayer%20error&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) as there seems to be no proper documentation and concrete steps to resolve the error.