# MediaPlayer's subtitle feature is not working (SRT file)

Tags: android, media-player, subtitle

I am trying to show the subtitle from the .srt file. (For Android 4.1+)
Both mp4 file and srt file exist in the device.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnPreparedListener{

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
SurfaceView playerSurfaceView;
TextView tv_subtitle;
String videoSrc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/video.mp4";
String subTitleSrc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/sub.srt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playerSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.playersurface);
    tv_subtitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle);
    surfaceHolder = playerSurfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoSrc);
        mediaPlayer.setOnTimedTextListener(new MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimedText(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, final TimedText timedText) {
                if (timedText != null) {
                    Log.d("test", "subtitle: " + timedText.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.addTimedTextSource(subTitleSrc, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/playersurface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

OnTimedTextListener is not being called. My Target SDK is 22 and my devices are above Android 4.1

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Same problem E/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player]﹕ THIS SUBTITLE NO DECODER 0x53526970 E/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player]﹕ NO SUBTITLE DATA FOUND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Answer. 
Credit: [Looking for a working example of addTimedTextSource for adding subtitle to a video from an .srt file in Android 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422673/looking-for-a-working-example-of-addtimedtextsource-for-adding-subtitle-to-a-vid)

mediaPlayer.selectTrack() method was missing in my code.

Here's the complete code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnPreparedListener{

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
SurfaceView playerSurfaceView;
TextView tv_subtitle;
String videoSrc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/video.mp4";
String subTitleSrc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/sub.srt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playerSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.playersurface);
    tv_subtitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle);
    surfaceHolder = playerSurfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoSrc);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();

        mediaPlayer.addTimedTextSource(subTitleSrc, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
        int textTrackIndex = findTrackIndexFor(
                MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_TIMEDTEXT, mediaPlayer.getTrackInfo());
        if (textTrackIndex >= 0) {
            mediaPlayer.selectTrack(textTrackIndex);
        } else {
            Log.w("test", "Cannot find text track!");
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnTimedTextListener(new MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimedText(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, final TimedText timedText) {
                if (timedText != null) {
                    Log.d("test", "subtitle: " + timedText.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

private int findTrackIndexFor(int mediaTrackType, MediaPlayer.TrackInfo[] trackInfo) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < trackInfo.length; i++) {
        if (trackInfo[i].getTrackType() == mediaTrackType) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}